# a tag not redirecting

Tags: html, href

I have a simple HTML code with an HTML a element and some text and an icon inside the tag. The hover function works well since the cursor changes form, but when I click on it nothing happens.

```
<div id="cart-block">
    <div class="blockcart cart-preview active leo-blockcart show-leo-loading" data-refresh-url="//novaled.cl/module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax">
        <div class="header popup-title">
            <a rel="nofollow " href="//novaled.cl/carrito?action=show">
                <i class="material-icons shopping-cart"></i>
                <span class="hidden-md-down cart">Carrito</span>
                <span class="cart-products-count">(1)</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="cssload-piano" style="display: block;">
            <div class="cssload-rect1"></div>
            <div class="cssload-rect2"></div>
            <div class="cssload-rect3"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

It works well and redirects to the page when I right click on it and choose "Open in a new tab".

I also tried inspecting the element and clicking the link directly from the href attribute, and it does work that way too.

This is the website https://novaled.cl, and the link is on the top right corner. It is the link that shows the shopping cart when there are articles in it.

Comment: If the hover effect works/the cursor changes, then is not an html/css issue. Most likely there's some js code catching the click and preventing the default action.

Comment: What Gabriel said is the likely case. There's some kind of JS errors being reported in the browser console, related to leofeature_cart.js. The problem could be the listener for the link, or it could be another JS function throwing an error stopping the listener from functioning.